# Not getting correct value in dataString in jQuery/Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

In my ajax script below when I do `console.log` for duration it returns `<select name="duration" id="duration">` instead of the value. I think for this reason my function is not working properly. I am not getting any response back from the PHP page and the loading image keeps on loading.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function() {
        var dataString = {
            quantity: $("#quantity").val(),
            duration: $("select[name='duration']").val()
        };
        console.log(duration);
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType : "json",
            url: "rent-process.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: true,
      beforeSend: function(){
                $("#submit").hide();
                $("#loading-rent").show();
      },
            success: function(json){
                $("#loading-rent").hide();
                $("#submit").show();
                $(".message").html(json.status).fadeIn();
                $('#wallet-av').html('$' + json.wallet);
                $('#ref-av').html(json.referrals);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: You miss the object, you can't just call a key in the object out of nowhere, what you need is `console.log(dataString.duration);`

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)